# Rails input nested content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have an submit_tag or input button, however you wanna call it, but I can't get the Text + Font-Awesome icon to work together.

I tryied like this

```
%input{type: "submit", name: "A", "data-theme" => "b"}
  %i.icon-time
  = "Finish"
```

But the icon and the text are outside the input tag(    ... )

I tryied to use

```
= content_tag :input, type: "submit", name: "A", "data-theme" => "b" do
   %i.icon-time
   = "Finish"
```

but the same problem, the %i was left outside.

with button_tag it looks good, but the content is not submitted to the controller. ( maybe because the html tag is button and not input )

How can I get this working?

Comment: It most definitely should submit with the button tag. A simple <button>A</button> would suffice to submit a form.

Comment: i am using a form_tag path, method: :put

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How did you get out of it. I don't understand your comments ...

Comment: I did it :) . Sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the application.html.haml I have the following

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
= javascript_include_tag "disable_ajax"
```

In the application.js

```
//= require jquery.mobile-1.3.0
```

In the disable_ajax.js

```
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; // Here is where I fix the problem
});
```

The key is to include the jquery mobile first

Answer (score 1):

Check your console for any errors. I feel like you may just have a css problem. If the button tag works for you, you could easily add a jquery fix.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

From what I can see that is the only fix for nesting content inside of a form submit.

P.S. You don't have to write `= "Finish"`, you could just write `Finish!`, HAML will insert it as plain text wither way.

Comment: Actually, i just figured out where the bug is. There is some weird stuff going on in the jquery mobile. The url-s are not correctly updated, no matter what the tag is button or input. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Maybe you should dynamically add the jQuery mobile only with a certain subdomain

Comment: I fixed it. I set $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; in the jquery mobile init function, now it works :)

Comment: Awesome. You should post that as the answer